# Vintage cup and cone bb

Tags: bottom-bracket, vintage

I am restoring an old bike and have got stuck, after removing the lock ring I attempted to remove the spanner fitting as seen on the photos, the fitting is very thin and so the spanner is slipping off not allowing me to put any pressure to release it.
Use the pics below.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Charlie
[image: bicycle bottom bracket side view]

[image: bicycle bottom bracket top view]

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you stop using a spanner.  That way leads to damaged parts, damaged knuckles, and tears.

Instead, get a socket of the correct size, and a ratchet bar to turn it.

Finally, have a good look at the visible threads and make sure you're turning it the right way, which will be the same turning direction used to remove the locknut.

You can do this, just take time and think ahead.

Comment: Thanks, I will use a socket and I removed the locking counter clockwise so that way.

Comment: Also use penetrating oil at least two days ahead of the intervention. Clean off any excess before using the nut to avoid slippage. BTW another good tool is a bench-vise to grip the nut firmly and use the seat-tube for leverage.

Comment: If you still have trouble, add some heat to the outside of the bb casing.

Answer (score -1):

When removing a bottom bracket, since the available surface is so narrow, it helps to use a proper [bottom bracket tool](https://www.parktool.com/product/crank-and-bottom-bracket-wrench-hcw-4).

Measure the distance between opposite flat sides and then search for "bottom bracket wrench" + (size), e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=bottom+bracket+wrench+36mm

They generally look something like this:
[image: bottom bracket tool]

Comment: In this case, from the photos it seems that the non-drive side cup has a hex fitting more appropriate for a hex socket than a two-flat tool. The opposite drive side does indeed seem to have only two flats, but Sheldon Brown cautions against using such a non-clamping tool for DS cup removal due to the large forces expected to be required.  More info in this current question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77688/what-type-of-bottom-bracket-does-my-bike-have